# Code Repetition Between KubeFlow Components

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I've got a question I think should be simple. I am writing a KubeFlow pipeline and am running into a lot of places with code repetition. Normally what I'd do is break this out into a function and maybe put it in a `utils.py` file and `import utils`. The question is this:

How do I do something similar if I have tons of repetition between my KubeFlow components? Alternatively, shouldn't I share code between components and in that case, how so?

Currently I am defining the same methods in the top of many of my components and use these later in the same component. I would like to only define these functions once. Is this possible?

Comment: One way to do this is to use ZenML (https://github.com/zenml-io/zenml) to write your pipelines, and use the Kubeflow orchestrator (https://docs.zenml.io/guides/functional-api/deploy-to-production) to deploy them to Kubeflow. The way ZenML handles steps you can re-use code across pipelines. I hesitate to put this as the main answer as im the co-creator of ZenML, but wanted to give you a tip if its helpful